# Css - White margin on top of a web page

Tags: html, css, margin

I've tried every possible combination of provided solutions to get rid of that margin such as:

```
body {    
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
```

and

```
* {
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
}
```

and

```
* {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
        outline: 0;
        font-size: 100%;
        vertical-align: baseline;
        background: transparent;
    }
```

but it won't help. In fact, i've tried almost every reasonably sounding solution from top 5 stackoverflow question on my topic and still got no result. My web page is:

```css
body {
  line-height: 1.6;
  color: #3a3a3a;
  font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
}

a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.main-header {
  background: #3acec2;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>My Page Title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>


  <header class="main-header">
    <h1 class="name"><a href="#">Header text here</a></h1>
  </header>
```

I use normalize version 7.0 up to date on 30.08.

Comment: can you provide working snippet code..?

Comment: can you attach a screenshot of your problem or jsfiddle?

Comment: The margin is coming from the `h1` element

Comment: It’s called collapsing margins, see https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins

Comment: @Danield yes it is. _“The top margin of an in-flow block element collapses with its first in-flow block-level child's top margin if the element has no top border, no top padding, and the child has no clearance.”_ is the part that applies here.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rowf0n5g/

Here you can clearly see the white margin on top of a web page

Comment: Solved by adding: .main-header {
paddin-top: 1em 0;
}

Comment: @Danield yes, but they did not remove the default margin-top a h1 gets applied from the browser stylesheet. And because the quoted condition is true, that margin gets applied to the `.main-header` parent element instead of the h1, pushing the _parent_ down. Check this example, and see how the effect changes once you add the border-top to the header: https://jsfiddle.net/yfxd613f/

Comment: @CBroe ok sorry I think I misunderstood the question, the OP wants the margin from the h1 - he just wants the background from the main-header to start at top left of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<h1>` margin here actually comes from `normalize.css` itself:

```css
/**
 * Correct the font size and margin on `h1` elements within `section` and
 * `article` contexts in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari.
 */

h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 0.67em 0;
}
```

And of course tag selector is more specific than universal selector, that's why solutions with `*` don't work.

The actual solution is very simple - in `style.css`:

```css
h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove h1 `margin-top` and margin of `body` tag.

```css
body {
  line-height: 1.6;
  color: #3a3a3a;
  font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
  margin:0;
}
a { 
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.main-header {
  background: #3acec2;
}
.main-header h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>My Page Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<header class="main-header">
    <h1 class="name"><a href="#">Header text here</a></h1>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```